# Python Dataframe: Date Columns Reformatting "NaTType does not support strftime" Error

Tags: python, date, strftime, reformat

I'm trying to reformat the following column names.  They all have been converted to datetime columns already.

The code works for the first 3 columns in my list.  However, the last two columns breaks it.

date_columns = ['DTI', 'DTO', 'DTD', 'DTE', 'DTINS']

```
for i in date_columns:
    df_EVENT5_13[i] = df_EVENT5_13[i].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Below is the error I get:

```
ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
df_EVENT5_13[i] = df_EVENT5_13[i].dt.date